# How to register a click but still have a normal ahref

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

On a webpage I have several links to items, for example:

```
<a href = "/view-item.php?id=1">View item 1</a>
<a href = "/view-item.php?id=2">View item 2</a>
<a href = "/view-item.php?id=3">View item 3</a>
```

For SEO reasons I want to have a normal ahref, but when someone clicks on the link, I want to register the click in a database so I can see how many times an item has been clicked on.

I think somehow with an Ajax call that will register the click in the database, but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help!

This is what I've done and works:

```
<a class="some-link" id="1" href = "/view-item.php?id=1">View item 1</a><br>
<a class="some-link" id="2" href = "/view-item.php?id=2">View item 2</a><br>
<a class="some-link" id="3" href = "/view-item.php?id=3">View item 3</a><br>

<script>
 $('.some-link').on('click',function(){

var id = $(this).attr('id')


$.ajax({
    url: "/click-count.php",    
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    data:  {
        method: "UpdateClickCount",
        id:id 
     },
    dataType: "json",             
    success: function (data) {

    }     
});

})
```

The click-count.php is called where the database is updated.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would have done it

1. Register a click event.
2. Prevent its default behavior with `event.preventDefault();`
3. Save href attribute's value
4. Send an ajax and do the stuff
5. Now redirect to the url specified in href with `location.href = href;`

```js
$(".aLinks").on('click',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).href;
  $.ajax(...).success(function(){
  
   //Do something if you want
   
   location.href = href;
  })
 
});
```

```html
<a href = "/view-item.php?id=1" class="aLinks">View item 1</a>
```

Comment: live() function has been deprecated since jquery 1.7 and removed in 1.9. Better use on() to attach event handlers

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward approach is:

1. register a `click` event handler on the `a` elements
2. prevent the default behavior for the `click` event.
3. store the destination page in a new variable
4. and then do you stuff in your event handler, like XHR
5. after finishing you stuff, set the `window.location.href` property to the destination you saved in step 3.

Here's some code without using jQuery:

```js
const manyA = [...document.querySelectorAll("a")];
manyA.forEach(a => {
  // register the click event
  a.addEventListener("click", event => {
    // prevent the default behaviour
    event.preventDefault();
    // get destination for link
    const destination = event.target.getAttribute("href");
    // do the XHR stuff
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'myservice/username?id=some-unique-id');
    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        alert('User\'s name is ' + xhr.responseText);
        /// redirect your user to the destination page
        window.location.href = destination;
      }
      else {
        alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
    });
});
```

```html
<a href="some.html">Some Link</a>
<a href="other.html">Some Other Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `onclick` handler and prevent the default behavior using the event.preventDefault.Inside this function make the request to save the data to db

```js
function test(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.href);
  return true;
}
```

```html
<a href="/view-item.php?id=1" onclick="test(event)">View item 1</a>
<a href="/view-item.php?id=2" onclick="test(event)">View item 2</a>
<a href="/view-item.php?id=3" onclick="test(event)">View item 3</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set id to `a` tag and add a event listener to that then call service on back-end to insert to db

```
<a class="some-btn" id="btn-1" href = "/view-item.php">View item 1</a>
<a class="some-btn" id="btn-2" href = "/view-item.php">View item 2</a>
<a class="some-btn" id="btn-3" href = "/view-item.php">View item 3</a>

<script>
 $('.some-btn').on('click',function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id')
//... then send id to your service with ajax or axios

})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<a>` tags can be given an `href` attribute or an `onclick` attribute, or both. The `onclick` attribute can point to a JavaScript function defined elsewhere:

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function logClick() {
    console.log("Clicked!");
  }
  </script>
  <a onclick="logClick()">Click Here!</a>
</body>
```

This attribute can be assigned in JavaScript with the `Element.addEventListener` function:

HTML:

```
<a id="link">Click Here!</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function logClick() {
  console.log("Clicked!");
}

const aTag = document.getElementById("link");
aTag.addEventListener("click", logClick);
```

So create your POST request in a JavaScript function, and pass the function somehow to the HTML `<a>` element's `click` event.